# How to display the time as 1 mins ago using angular2-moment

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-moment

```
<div>{{2018-04-16T05:56:45.200Z | amTimeAgo}}</div>
```

The above gives me results after a minute as `1 minutes ago` but I want the result as `1 mins ago` How can I achieve this using angular2-moment npm module?

I have to use this module only to fulfill the result.The link is provided[here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-moment)

Answer (score 1):

After reading the [code of the pipe](https://github.com/urish/ngx-moment/blob/master/src/time-ago.pipe.ts) you can see that it calls the moment constructor and the `from()` method like it is described in the [moment documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/).

After digging a little further about how to set the used strings I found this [configuration object in the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/). And with this knowledge I tried to [find something](https://github.com/urish/ngx-moment/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+updatelocale) setting this property bringing me to this [open issue](https://github.com/urish/ngx-moment/issues/108). So there seems to be in interims solution which you can (maybe) use. There was also already a [try to solve this problem](https://github.com/urish/ngx-moment/pull/142).

But it seems to need some kind of polishing (move positional parameters to object properties). Maybe you can take the job and improve the code?